# How to map sql result set to my entity model when joining multiple table and there is relationship in model

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to join tables and then map return result to one entity.
But I am not sure why this keeps failing? Can someone from the community help me with this?

My Model class

````
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;



@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "JobApplicationModel.findApplicationByScoreMapping", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = JobApplicationModel.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "id"), @FieldResult(name = "job_id", column = "jobId")
}))
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "JobApplicationModel.findApplicationByScore", query = "SELECT ja.id, ja.job_id " +
                "FROM application ja JOIN job_score_v2 js ON " +
                "ja.job_id=js.job_id  INNER JOIN application_status asm ON " +
                "ja.id=asm.application_id WHERE ja.user_id=:userId AND " +
                "ja.is_deleted=false AND asm.status <>:status ORDER by js.score DESC ",
                resultSetMapping = "JobApplicationModel.findApplicationByScoreMapping"),
        @NamedNativeQuery(name = "JobApplicationModel.findApplicationByScore.count", query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +
                "application ja JOIN job_score_v2 js ON ja.job_id=js.job_id " +
                "INNER JOIN application_status asm on ja.id=asm.application_id WHERE " +
                "ja.user_id user_id=:userId and ja.is_deleted=false AND asm.status <>:status "
                ,resultSetMapping = "JobApplicationModel.findApplicationByScoreMapping")
})

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="application")
public class JobApplicationModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "careers_application_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "careers_application_id_seq", sequenceName = "application_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private long jobId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;

    private Date created;

    @Column(name = "date_modified")
    private Date dateModified;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("jobId")
    @JoinColumn(name="job_id")
    JobsModel job;

    public JobApplicationModel(Date created, Date dateModified, boolean isDeleted) {
        this.created = created;
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public JobApplicationModel() {
    }

    public JobApplicationModel(long jobId, long userId, Date created, Date dateModified, boolean isDeleted) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.created = created;
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public long getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }

    public void setJobId(long jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getDateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    public void setDateModified(Date dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        isDeleted = deleted;
    }

    public JobsModel getJob() {
        return job;
    }

    public void setJob(JobsModel job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}```
````

My repo

Page findApplicationByScore(long userId, String status, Pageable pageable);

Error Trace

Hibernate: SELECT ja.id, ja.job_id, ja.created FROM application ja JOIN job_score_v2 js ON ja.job_id=js.job_id  INNER JOIN application_status asm ON ja.id=asm.application_id WHERE ja.user_id=? AND ja.is_deleted=false AND asm.status <>? ORDER by js.score DESC limit ?
[ WARN  ] [ 3854952d-3d77-4af7-b8ef-a9ed49ef96b2 ]  SqlExceptionHelper                       : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
[ ERROR ] [ 3854952d-3d77-4af7-b8ef-a9ed49ef96b2 ]  SqlExceptionHelper                       : The column name created2_0_0_ was not found in this ResultSet.
[ ERROR ] [ 3854952d-3d77-4af7-b8ef-a9ed49ef96b2 ]  RollbarServiceImpl                       : could not execute query; SQL [SELECT ja.id, ja.job_id, ja.created FROM application ja JOIN job_score_v2 js ON ja.job_id=js.job_id  INNER JOIN application_status asm ON ja.id=asm.application_id WHERE ja.user_id=? AND ja.is_deleted=false AND asm.status <>? ORDER by js.score DESC]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT ja.id, ja.job_id, ja.created FROM application ja JOIN job_score_v2 js ON ja.job_id=js.job_id  INNER JOIN application_status asm ON ja.id=asm.application_id WHERE ja.user_id=? AND ja.is_deleted=false AND asm.status <>? ORDER by js.score DESC]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.findApplicationByScore(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.findApplicationByScore(Unknown Source)
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.service.impl.JobsServiceImpl.getUserJobApplication(JobsServiceImpl.java:348)
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.controller.JobController.getUserJobApplications(JobController.java:72)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.auth.UpgradAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(UpgradAuthorizationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2890)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2142)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:177)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
... 96 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name created2_0_0_ was not found in this ResultSet.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2748)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getTimestamp(PgResultSet.java:2666)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:84)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3088)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1907)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1835)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1808)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1660)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1044)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:995)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887)
... 117 common frames omitted
[ DEBUG ] [ 3854952d-3d77-4af7-b8ef-a9ed49ef96b2 ]  RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler       : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT ja.id, ja.job_id, ja.created FROM application ja JOIN job_score_v2 js ON ja.job_id=js.job_id  INNER JOIN application_status asm ON ja.id=asm.application_id WHERE ja.user_id=? AND ja.is_deleted=false AND asm.status <>? ORDER by js.score DESC]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]
[ DEBUG ] [ 3854952d-3d77-4af7-b8ef-a9ed49ef96b2 ]  FirstRequestInterceptor                  : [ END ] - Request processing completed....
[ DEBUG ] [ 3854952d-3d77-4af7-b8ef-a9ed49ef96b2 ]  FilterChainProxy                         : /error has an empty filter list
[ DEBUG ] [ 951ca2cd-ab36-4bda-b12b-7efec2e33e36 ]  FirstRequestInterceptor                  : [ START ] - Request processing started....
[ DEBUG ] [ 951ca2cd-ab36-4bda-b12b-7efec2e33e36 ]  FirstRequestInterceptor                  : [ END ] - Request processing completed....